# "Error: Could not refresh access token" occurs in Google Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

What I want to do is to execute the cloud function written in Node.js and create vm instance in GCE.

I've already implemented the cloud function to create vm instance in GCE. I tried to execute the cloud function several times, but vm instance was not created.

Cloud functions runtime: Node.js 8

The source code is like the below.
index.js

```
const Compute = require('@google-cloud/compute');
const compute = new Compute();
exports.startInstance = function startInstance(req, res) {
    const zone = compute.zone('us-central1-c');
    zone.createVM("test", {os: 'ubuntu'});
    console.log('instance start successfully');
res.status(200).send('Success start instance');
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "startInstance",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "create gce instance",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/compute": "1.0.0"
  }
}
```

The error is like the below sometimes occurred.

```
"textPayload": "Error: Could not refresh access token: Unsuccessful response status code. Request failed with status code 500\n    at Gaxios.request (/srv/node_modules/gaxios/build/src/gaxios.js:70:23)\n    at <anonymous>\n    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)",
  "insertId": "000000-58d51a97-122c-4531-9c9a-00b19695e93d",
  "resource": {
    "type": "cloud_function",
    "labels": {
      "project_id": "$project_id",
      "region": "asia-northeast1",
      "function_name": "function-2"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2019-07-25T12:44:02.802Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "labels": {
    "execution_id": "jjcat6rtw49n"
  },
  "logName": "projects/$project_id/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions",
  "trace": "projects/$project_id/traces/be422ca287727cdf58d8275925c176ab",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2019-07-25T12:44:08.781094017Z"
}
```

Could you tell me why vm instance in GCE isn't created?

Comment: the way you decide that it is a "success" is questionable ...and it is called `GCE`. starting and creating an instance also isn't the same thing.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. GCE is correct as you mentioned. Now I edited it.

Answer (score 1):

I took your code as-is to reproduce and I got the error:

> Error: Invalid value for field 'zone': 'us-central1'. Unknown zone

I updated your code to use 'us-central1-c' zone for example and it created the VM successfully.

Comment: Thank you for confirming. I modified the source code and tried it, but the same error in the description occurred. I just fixed the source code in the description, too.

Comment: So the "Could not refresh access token" error still happens sometimes but otherwise your function successfully creates VMs right?

Comment: Currently, "Could not refresh access token" error still happens, and VM instance creation is not successful.

Comment: Any luck with this? I have run into a similar problem